# Python Qt5 - Font awesome icons on QTextBrowser

Tags: python, pyqt5, font-awesome

The question is simple:
How can i use fontawesome icons in QTextBrowser?

What i have done:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.0
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(346, 194)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style><script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/b55315bcbf.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8.25pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-size:14pt; font-weight:600;\">Test text</span><i class=\"fas fa-smile\"></i></p></body></html>"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#details) about QTextEdit (which is inherited by QTextBrowser) reports:

> QTextEdit is an advanced WYSIWYG viewer/editor supporting rich text formatting using HTML-style tags [...]. Rich text can be described using a subset of HTML 4 markup.
> The rich text support in Qt is designed to provide a fast, portable and efficient way to add reasonable online help facilities to applications, and to provide a basis for rich text editors. If you find the HTML support insufficient for your needs you may consider the use of Qt WebKit, which provides a full-featured web browser widget.

Considering the above, this obviously means that there's no `<script>` support, that's exactly because QTextBrowser inherits from QTextEdit, which is a widget to *write* text documents, and should certainly not support dynamic contents like external scripts.

These are the only possible solutions, each one with its pros and cons:

1. install the font on the system: it's system-wide (or at least user-wide), you can just load the font with the correct tag; unfortunately it requires administrator permissions and there's no crossplatform way to install a font from Qt;
2. bundle the font in the application and load it with [`QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontdatabase.html#addApplicationFont): usually the best solution, it behaves as the font was installed on the system, but without any installation requirements; the font *has* to be packaged with the application, which might be an issue for some licenses;
3. use Qt WebKit widgets ([QWebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html), etc); it supports all the features of a modern browser, but if you only need to display some text with a custom font, using it is a huge overshoot;

Comment: Is there any way to use html <iframe> tag instead?

Comment: @ChrisP No. As already explained, the rich text support is limited and does *not* support advanced/dynamic content: adding an iframe wouldn't change anything, since the controller would still be the QTextEdit. As explained in the documentation, Qt has only a limited [supported HTML subset](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html). If you want to use the icons of font awesome, download the desktop version and get the SVG files you need, then use `QIcon('pathToIcon.svg').pixmap(size)` to get the pixmap.

Comment: Ok, i will try. Can i use this? https://pypi.org/project/QtAwesome/

Comment: Don't ask if you can use it, try it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might use the `.setHtml(your_HTML_string)` from the `QtWidgets.QTextBrowser` widget from `PyQt5`

Your html data should use this format for the image:

```
img src="data:image/png;base64,[your_encoded_base64_string_image]"
```

You could use the https://pypi.org/project/QtAwesome/ icons and just get the image and encoded. For this purpose you could use the `base64` python library to encode the image from `QtAwesome` library like:

**Python pseudo code: **

```
import base64
pm = base64.b64encode(img_file)
your_encoded_base64_string_image = pm.decode("utf-8")
```

**your_HTML_string example: **

```
<html>

<head><meta name="qrichtext" content="1" />
<style type="text/css">
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
</style>
</head>

<body style=" font-family:'Arial Unicode MS'; font-size:10pt; font-weight:600; font-style:normal;">

<p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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 " width="17" height="17" style="vertical-align: top;" /> Tue Nov 30 08:57:36 2021: Importar Archivo Red, Exitoso! 
<br><img src="data:image/png;base64,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 " style='vertical-align:top' width="17" height="17"> Tue Nov 30 08:58:12 2021: Coordenadas de proyecto estan fuera de raster disponible, verificar!
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Marcelo.